# Data binding performance in AS3 / Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, data-binding

What are the various levels of performance in the different ways of binding?

- `ChangeWatcher.watch`
- `addEventListener`
- `BindingUtils.bindProperty`
- `MXML {}`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an answerable question without a significant amount of research.  Are you having problems with performance?  Do you believe those problems are related to binding in some manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex's databinding is very heavy as it uses the magic strings event system that adds a lot of extra code in addition to other performance crap it adds.  If your looking for performance bind manually.  Here's a very in depth report on your exact question though: http://www.slideshare.net/michael.labriola/diving-in-the-flex-data-binding-waters-presentation